# Android OCR library not support

Tags: java, android

I am create one app ocr reading from camera, get capture image from camera and and recognize word frome that picture or library and get result as character so simply i have find out it from git hub from [**here**](https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr/tree/master/android) and i have import those project in my eclipse . but and when i have open it it get package  error regarding no library support of tesseract API, but i found that that already configur in that project so how it raise error. so please help me out this...

Comment: which platform Android / ios ?

Comment: @VipulShah I would assume Android, because OP is using Java.

Comment: @VipulShah ya its for Android.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import  [https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/tree/master/tess-two) as library project and reference it into your project

I would suggest you to refer to this tutorial its very concise and eay to learn.

http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/

Comment: the are jni so i need to import jni folder or entire project

Comment: you will need to install NDK.and import whole project

Comment: can you give me steps to do this